# Building a supporting structure for a 600L (160 gallon) aquarium

Tags: structural

I have acquired a used 600L (160 gallon) glass aquarium. Leak test has been a success. Now I need to build a supporting structure to keep it lifted from the ground. Conceivably, it will weight less than 800kg, as it can contain a maximum of 600kg of water, and I'm guessing the weight of the glass itself at about 100kg, with another 100kg added for good measure.

Visual appeal is not a priority: it's in a service room, so I will probably just surround whatever structure I build with spray-painted plywood panels. As such, I would like to build or buy the structure as cheaply as possible. The only extra requirement is that this structure has some empty space in it to install the water pumps and maybe store aquarium-related supplies.

Some options I have considered are:

- Get metal shelving or build one with a composable shelving system - promising but high-load bearing ones tend to cost a fortune
- Build a piece of wooden furniture - not really my area of expertise, my woodworking is pretty basic; hiring someone in this area can be quite costly
- Build a [-shaped structure with bricks, have a plywood panel under the aquarium to distribute the weight over it; feels unstable without cementing

At the moment, it feels like the most promising one is building a piece of wooden furniture. But this is a lot of weight, and while I do some woodworking I don't feel like I have sufficient experience.

How would you suggest me to build such a structure?

Comment: First what type of surface will it be on?  A cement floor might be okay, but a wooden floor on joists not so okay.  Length and width of the bottom?

Comment: This might be beter answered on the woodworking site

Comment: @crip659 it's going to be on heavy-duty tiles. Ground floor.

Comment: Tiles that are laid on concrete?

Comment: @Huesmann that's more difficult to say. I was a child when the house was completely restructured, so I don't know for a fact. The floor feels completely stiff and full when hitting it with an hammer or jumping on it. Is there a non-distructive way I could find out?

Comment: Is there a space below this floor, or is it a slab on grade?

Comment: @Huesmann there is not space that I know of below this floor. It's a small single-floor masonry building that we added on top of nothing next to the house during the restructuring, as a utility room. We know of an underground well on our property, but it's at least 20 meters from it; same with a cellar. I'm not sure whether it's a slab on grade or a different kind of structure; I'm not very familiar with building techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the floor will take it (perhaps your "service room" has a concrete slab floor) using concrete blocks (not bricks) to build a stand to support plywood (and a sheet of extruded polystyrene (XPS) insulation for good measure between the tank and the plywood - helps to prevent small irregularities from cracking the tank) is the least cost, most sturdy way to get there. It might not be a good idea in an area where earthquakes are common, though.

Stack the blocks properly (cores vertical) not bone-headedly (cores horizontal) without mortar. Because of the width of the blocks, they are stable for "reasonable height of an aquarium stand" and the basic structure has been proven thousands of times over as a dorm-room bookshelf on the cheap. You can use wider blocks (10" or 12" rather than 6" or 8" - certainly not 4") for greater stability.

Rather than a [-shape, provide 3 or 4 stacks that support the full width of the base of the aquarium. The span between stacks should not be too long, but can provide space for pumps, etc. How many stacks depends how long the tank is (160 gallons appears not to be one of the standard sizes) - or, you can have 2 stacks and use steel shapes to support between stacks, similar to standard metal aquarium stands.

Comment: Floor is tiles. It's very flat, but should I use something as a bottom layer between the bricks and the floor? Height of the stand is going to be ~24" total. So not very tall. Having multiple stacks is not an issue, the space we need for the pumps is relatively little, width-wise.

Comment: The aquarium is exactly 2 meters (6.56 ft) wide.

Comment: A layer of XPS or a solid rubber mat between the blocks and the tile would be kinder to the tile.